# Replacing Spring bean injection via XML with annotation injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to declare and inject a bean through annotations. It was previously done through XML, but I need to apply on a Spring Boot project.

Here is the source xml

```
<oauth:resource-details-service id="rds">
    <oauth:resource
            id="oauth1"
            key="${key}"
            secret="${secret}"
            request-token-url="${token}"
            user-authorization-url="${user-auth}"
            access-token-url="${accesstokenurl}">
    </oauth:resource>
</oauth:resource-details-service>
```

The bean was later used like this

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth.consumer.client.OAuthRestTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="oauth1"/>
</bean>
```

The only way I found is through direct instantiation

```
BaseProtectedResourceDetails resourceDetails = new BaseProtectedResourceDetails();
resourceDetails.set...
resourceDetails.set...
OAuthRestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuthRestTemplate(resourceDetails);
```

What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: You can initialize `BaseProtectedResourceDetails` in your configuration java class and then initialize bean for `OAuthRestTemplate` and pass the initialized bean of `BaseProtectedResourceDetails` in constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use @Bean annotation in your main class for example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application{

 @Bean
 public OAuthRestTemplate getAuth(){
   BaseProtectedResourceDetails resourceDetails = new BaseProtectedResourceDetails();
   resourceDetails.set...
   resourceDetails.set...

   return new OAuthRestTemplate(resourceDetails);
 }
}
```

and after use @Autowired to inject the object

```
@Autowired
private OAuthRestTemplate oAuthRestTemplate;
```

Comment: What if the resourceDetails needs configuration defined in a property file (like a secret key), having a field annotated with @Value could be work or would it be empty when the bean is created?

Comment: you can try to use Environment object like this : 
@Resource Environment env;
and get property like :    final String myPropertyValue = environment.getProperty("myProperty");

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you are searching for this explanation. But if I understand you question then following information may help you.

For Sample configuration class you can see [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm) example.

```
package com.tutorialspoint;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

@Configuration
public class TextEditorConfig {

   @Bean 
   public TextEditor textEditor(){
      return new TextEditor( spellChecker() );
   }

   @Bean 
   public SpellChecker spellChecker(){
      return new SpellChecker( );
   }
}
```

And for registering configuration class, you can see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8076045).

See [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/) for @Service, @Component, @Repository, @Controller, @Autowired related example.