# Using Spring Mvc WebApplicationInitializer, But No mapping found for HTTP request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config, request-mapping

I am setup a sample Code base using Spring MVC in Eclipse and JBoss 6.2.

But I get '404' with http://localhost:8080/rest/simple/main

Jboss log as below:

> *2015-07-29 11:51:27,356 ERROR [controller.simpleController] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) get request*
>
> 2015-07-29 11:51:27,391 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/rest/WEB-INF/views/main.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Directory :

```
>rest-server-simple
 > -src
  > -main
     -java
      -config
         -InitConfig.java
         -ServletConfig.java
      -controller
         -simpleController.java
  > -webapp
   > -WEB-INF
       -jboss-web.xml
       >views
        -main.jsp
```

InitConfig:

```
public class InitConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {
  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
  ctx.register(ServletConfig.class); 
  ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
  registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
  registration.addMapping("/*");  }}
```

ServletConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc  
@ComponentScan(basePackages ="controller")
public class ServletConfig {
  @Bean
  public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {  
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();  
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");  
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp"); 
    return viewResolver;  
  }
}
```

jboss-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<jboss-web>  
    <context-root>/rest</context-root>  
</jboss-web>
```

simpleController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/simple")
public class simpleController {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(simpleController.class);
  @RequestMapping(value = "/main", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String hello(){
    logger.error("get request");
    return "main";
  }
}
```

Comment: When I replace InitConfig.java with web.xml  ,   

http://localhost:8080/rest/simple/main IS OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
registration.addMapping("/*");
```

Change it to

```
registration.addMapping("/");
```

There is a difference between `/*` and `/` .
`/*` indicates that every request will be handled by `DispatcherServlet`, in this case retrieval of a `jsp` or anything like `.../abc.xyz` etc will also be forwarded to `Dispatcher`, so when controller requests for a `view` it actually looks for `RequestMapping` mapped for `/WEB-INF/views/main.jsp` but

`/` tells container that only those requests that do not have `pathinfo i.e /rest/simple/main` will be handled by `DispatcherServlet`.

#### UPDATE#1

Hmm.. What I have found that `jboss AS 7` doesn't like overriding `default servlet` i.e. `/` without `web.xml` and hence you are still getting `404` and not even getting anything on the logger, Reason being simple is that `Dispatcher` is never mapped to any `url`. If you want to check that just add following after `addMapping("/*");`

```
 System.out.println("registration.getMappings() = " + registration.getMappings());
```

It works fine with `Tomcat >= 7.0.15` or `WildFly` have checked on both.

To make it work on `JBoss7` there are few options:
1. Change `DispatcherServlet` mapping from `/` to `*.htm` or something except `DefaultServlet Mapping`.
2. Switch your Configuration to `web.xml`. You will have to initialize `DispatcherServlet` there and pass Annotated class as `contextConfigLocation.  [Check here for REF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075790/how-to-register-spring-configuration-annotated-class-instead-of-applicationcont)

Comment: It works fine when I change web server with Tomcat.
So... Jboss is the main cause of problem.